# Is there a name for differential equations of two variables that do not have (nontrivial) solutions in these two forms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Say $f(x,y)$ follows some PDE such that no nontrivial solutions exist of the form:

$$f(x,y) =X(x)Y(y) $$

and

$$f(x,y) = X(x)+ Y(y)$$

The first one refers to separable and non-separable PDEs; but what about the second one? Is there a name for the combination of these?